# jMagick use Eclipse By Windows 64 bit

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

Captures the jMagic in Eclipse, can you do to debug locally?

I first, Download "jmagick-win-6.3.9-Q8.zip" and "ImageMagick-6.3.9-0-Q8-windows-dll.exe" from the following [This URL](http://www.jmagick.org/6.3.9/).

Than thawed "jmagick-win-6.3.9-Q8.zip", incorporating the "jMagic.jar" to the Eclipse project.

Next, I try to install the "imageMagick".But, My pc can't connect to the network.
There, "imageMagick" installed on another PC and generated files bring to my pc, through a path.

I try debug the following code.

```
ImageInfo image = new ImageInfo("/test/test.jpg");
```

However, The following error message occurs.

```
jmagick can't find dependent libraries
```

Please let me know this problem.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: For a 64bit JRE version you need the x64 version of ImageMagic. I would try to use `ImageMagick-7.0.3-4-Q8-x64-dll.exe` from http://www.imagemagick.org and install it locally.

Comment: Robert, Thank you for the advice. I try to install the "ImageMagick-7.0.3-4-Q8-x64-dll.exe" on another PC and generated files bring to my PC. However, It does not change the symptoms. Probably I think Not possibly can and do not want to install to my pc. Somehow, try to install on my PC.